# Как указать входные файлы?

Tags: c++, linux, doxygen

У меня несколько каталогов с кодом и нужно сделать документацию на Doxygen в общем я создал Doxyfile
в meson.build в одной папке с Doxifile прописал :

```
doxyfile = configuration_data()
doxyfile.set('OUTPUT_DIRECTORY', meson.build_root()) 
configure_file(input: 'Doxyfile.in', output: 'Doxyfile',
    configuration: doxyfile) 
doxygen = find_program('doxygen')
if doxygen.found() # ninja doc генерирует документацию
    run_target('doc', command: [doxygen,
        join_paths(meson.build_root(), 'Doxyfile')]) 
endif
```

в Doxyfile добавил:

```
PROJECT_NAME = "My Project"
OUTPUT_DIRECTORY = @OUTPUT_DIRECTORY@
```

html папка билдится index.html присутсвует, вот только нет файлов которые я прокоментировал! 
Они появляются только в случае, если в Doxyfile прописать прямой путь к файлу:

```
INPUT = src/myproject/MyVector/MyVector.hh
```

Соответсвенно при таком действии я не смогу задействовать комментривание остальных файлов.
Кто нибудь может помочь разобраться с этой бедой?

Репа на [гите](https://github.com/Yarik2308/SystemProg/tree/master/Zadanie9), мб так легче будет понят в чем проблема.

Comment: Я использовал Google translate для перевода (я не читаю / не говорю по-русски), так что, может быть, хорошая идея перекреститься на английскую версию stackoverflow. Насколько я понимаю, я думаю, вы должны посмотреть на настройку конфигурации «RECURSIVE» (I used Google translate to translate (I don't read / speak Russian) so maybe a good idea to crosspost to the english version of stackoverflow. From what I understand I think you should have a look at the configuration setting `RECURSIVE`)

Comment: @albert thx a lot! That's what I needed, now it works!